# Excessive allocations in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7-emulator

I am running Windows Phone Performance Analysis tool on my Windows Phone App in Windows Phone Emulator.

I am getting warning of "Excessive Allocations reaching to more than 120%" in initial 4 seconds my app. However, when i run profiler with memory option, i see that memory consumption does not exceed more than 20MB of phone [emulator] memory.

This has caused a lot of confusion.

Kindly help on how to target those exceeded allocations and any suggestions to remove those bottlenecks

Thanx in advance

Comment: Can you post code for your App.xaml.cs ctor/Launchingm= methods (if doing anything extra and your mainpage.xaml.cs ctor/loaded/navigatedto methods

Comment: ya... on NavigatedTo events, I am loading application bar buttons and menu items. also, I am loading a background image at runtime from pictures.

Answer (score 1):

Try to pinpoint the part of the code that causes this. Start commenting out part of your code and see at what point the warning appears/dissapears

Comment: I am loading an image at runtime using ImageBrush. The image is retrieved from Media library. Can this be the major problem?

Comment: Try to skip this part and see what happens. If it start working then try to use smaller image and/or image that is stored in your app's sandbox